# Representation theory of inner forms

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I once heard something like "inner forms of reductive groups have the same representation theory".

Is this assertion misguided?

If this assertion is not misguided, then is there a precise statement to this effect (perhaps in Tannakian terms)?

Comment: Here I suspect that "same representaton theory" just refers to the classification by highest weights, without Tannakian implications.  See for exampe the long article by J. Tits in the PSPM volume 9 published by AMS after the 1965 Boulder summer institute, with tables at the end giving inner and oujter forms of the simple types.

Comment: "rushing in where angels fear to tread": the base fields would be local fields (or global fields) $k$. Irreducible admissible representations of $G(k)$ are "roughly" classified by (some special) homomorphisms of the Weil group of $k$ into the Langlands dual group $^L G$. The latter is determined only up to inner forms. For details see Borel's article in Corvallis volumes.

Comment: for example, if $D$ is a quaternionic division algebra over $k$, then representations of $GL_1(D)$ are in one one correspondence with supercuspidal representations of $GL_9K0$.

Comment: The statement "same representation theory" is not quite correct; somehow, it is enough to study only the reps of quasi split inner forms, because others can be read off from this case.

Comment: @Venkataramana, surely you mean $\operatorname{GL}_4(k)$, not $\operatorname{GL}_9$?

Comment: I meant $GL_2(k)$

Comment: @Venkataramana Don't you also mean discrete series, not supercuspidal, because the Steinberg representation of $GL_2(k)$ corresponds to the trivial representation of $GL_1(D)$? Not a big difference obviously, but important for some applications.

Comment: @Sawin: yes, the trivial representation slipped my mind

Comment: @Venkataramana, yes, of course you are right that it should be $\operatorname{GL}_2(k)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I vote for "misguided". The representation theory of inner forms are certainly not the "same". What is true (over a local field) is they have the same L-group. A precise version is: the L-packets for G embed in the L-packets for the quasisplit form (assuming the local Langlands conjectures of course).

Answer (score 4):

Well, it is not misguided if by "representation" you mean "algebraic representation". More generally, if $E$ is a right $G$-torsor over $Spec F$ and $X$ is a $G$-variety you can form a ``twisted form'' $E\wedge_G X=E\times X/(e,x)\sim (eg,gx)$ which is ${}_EG$-variety, where ${}_EG$ is the inner twisted form of $G$ corresponding to $E$. This gives an equivalence between the category of $G$-varieties and the category of ${}_EG$-varieties. The same construction applies to algebraic representations (and the equivalence is additive and preserves tensor products).

Comment: Indeed, I was mainly concerned with algebraic representations. Thanks for your response!